# TypeScript type for module name string

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, hot-module-replacement

**Background:**
TypeScript checks the modules that you try and import, and fails at compile-time if a string literal is used that does not match the name of an actual module or path to a supported file type.

For example `import {Component} from 'react'` and `import item from './item'` compile fine, but `import {Component} from 'reactt'` and `import item from './otem'` would fail to compile assuming that there is a `react` module installed and an `item.ts` file in the project but no `reactt` module installed and no `./otem` file with the extensions .ts, .js, .json, etc in the project.

**Problem:** I'm not sure how to create a function where one of the arguments is a string literal that **must** correspond to an actual module or supported file.

```
function customImportEffect(moduleName: module_string_literal) {
    ...
}
```

What type should `module_string_literal` be so that compile-time checking fails when incorrect inputs such as `'reactt'` or `'./otem'` are supplied as arguments?

**Reason for asking:**
I am trying to make a webpack file transformer (a.k.a. a loader) which adds code to the top of TypeScript files before they are transpiled, so users can have type-safe hot module reloading code. For example, imagine the following code being inserted above every typescript file before being transpiled to JS:

```
class HotModule {
    public static accept(moduleName: module_string_literal, onModuleReplace: Function(updatedModule: typeof import(moduleName)):void) {
        if(module.hot) {
            module.accept(moduleName.toString(), function() {
                onUpdate(require(moduleName.toString()))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then hot module reloading could be type-safe and appear more clean. Assuming that the default export from the ./item.ts file is an object with a member named `message`, one could write

```
HotModule.accept("./item", ({message: newMessage}) => {
    const oldMessage = message;
    messages[messages.indexOf(oldMessage)] = message = newMessage;
}
```

to implement hot reloading of the message instead of

```
if(module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept("./item", function() {
        const oldMessage = message;
        messages[messages.indexOf(oldMessage)] = message = require("./item");
    }
}
```

I am hoping this may be possible because since TypeScript v2.4 there has been the ability to asynchronously dynamically import modules, and the string literal supplied is checked for correctness, and incorrect string literals cause a compile-time failure.

Currently I'm just including `"types": ["webpack-env"]` in the `compilerOptions` object in my `tsconfig.json` file, but I'd like a hot module API which takes better advantage of TypeScript's checking toolset.

Comment: Also I'm curious if ttypescript (plugin-system for typescript) could somehow be used for this.

Answer (score 0):

make a module-type.d.ts somewhere with the content

```
import json from "./package.json" // or whereever your package json is
export type ModuleName=keyof typeof json["dependencies"]
```

you will need to enable jsonmodule in your tsconfig

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
```

then you import it wherever you need it

Comment: I was hoping to have a type which could exist in a library, meaning there would be no access to the client's package.json

Comment: well you could create a lbirary that imports from outside the module border ( doesnt seem liek a good idea) and well someone has to access the package.json